# SQL merge row from union result and calculate

Tags: sql, group-by, union

I'm quite new in SQl  This is my requirement.

```
TableA 
operation route measurement
A         No    200
A         Yes   300
B         No    400
B         Yes   500
```

I want this as **result**

```
Operation MeasurementNo  MeasurementYes  MeasureDifference
A         200            300             100
B         400            500             100
```

So the operation field has to be grouped. At the same time the two values of the measurement of the operation have to be merged to one row.

`The MeasureDifference = MeasurementYes -  MeasurementNo`.

It looks not that difficult too achieve with SQL, but I'm just a newbee. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use grouping and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  operation,
  SUM(CASE route WHEN 'No'  THEN measurement END) AS MeasurementNo,
  SUM(CASE route WHEN 'Yes' THEN measurement END) AS MeasurementYes,
  SUM(CASE route WHEN 'Yes' THEN measurement END)
  - SUM(CASE route WHEN 'No'  THEN measurement END) AS MeasurementDifference
FROM atable t
GROUP BY
  operation
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a join:

```
SELECT
    MNo.operation AS Operation,
    MNo.measurement AS MeasurementNo,
    MYes.measurement AS MeasurementYes,
    MYes.measurement - MNo.measurement AS MeasureDifference
FROM TableA AS MNo
JOIN TableA AS MYes
ON MNo.operation = MYes.operation
AND MNo.route = 'No'
WHERE MYes.route = 'Yes'
```